# Ansible - How to use shell module with brace expansion?

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible [core 2.15.2]. I am trying to create 32 empty directories using brace expansion.

```yaml
- name: Create panel directories in /vista
  shell: mkdir /vista/board{1..32}

- name: Change ownership of board directories
  shell: chown joe:joe /vista/board*
```

Ansible created one directory called `board{1..32}`.

How can I get the brace expansion to work? The ownership will be `root:root` so I want to change it to `joe` but I am not sure if that would work as written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brace expansion syntax (`mkdir /vista/board{1..32}` ) is Bash-specific syntax. When you use the `shell` module, Ansible will explicitly run `/bin/sh`. On many systems (in particular, Debian, Ubuntu, and derivatvies), `/bin/sh` is **not** Bash.

To use that syntax you would need to call out to bash explicitly:

```
- name: Create panel directories in /vista
  command: |
    bash -c 'mkdir -p /vista/board{1..32}'
```

This will do what you expect (create directories `/vista/board1` through `/vista/board32`). The disadvantage to this solution is that the task will always have a `changed` status.

Creating the directories individually via an Ansible loop over a `file` task would provide better feedback and would allow you to set ownership at the same time, but would probably be slower:

```
- name: Create panel directories in /vista
  file:
    state: directory
    path: /vista/board{{item}}
    owner: joe
    group: joe
  loop: "{{ range(1,32) }}"
```

Of course, if we replace `mkdir` with `install` in the first example, we can also combine creating the directories and setting ownership in a single task:

```
- name: Create panel directories in /vista
  command: |
    bash -c 'install -d -o joe -g joe /vista/board{1..32}'
```

---

As @Subzero123 points out in a comment, you can use the `executable` option of the `shell` module to accomplish the same thing:

```
- name: Create panel directories in /vista
  shell:
    executable: /bin/bash
    cmd: "install -d -o joe -g joe /vista/board{1..32}"
```

Comment: Ah, stackoverflow, I love you and your jealous -1s.

Comment: Thanks. The `install` command worked as intended. I didn't try the `mkdir` command. I did end up going with file module.

Comment: @larsks Isn't specifying `executable=/bin/bash` better than using the `bash` command all the time ?